# Explicit functional relationship

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

I have an implicit relationship between dependent variable $y$ and independent variable $x  \in \mathbb{R}$ which read as follows:

$$ \frac{(y-1)^{\alpha + 1}}{y} =  \exp{(\beta x)}$$

Here $\alpha, \beta $ are positive real constants with $ 0 < \alpha \leq 2$.

I am getting some expression for $\alpha = 1$. Can someone please help me to find out the explicit relation between $y$ and $x$ for other values of $\alpha$.

Thank you.

Comment: What has this to do with combinatorics?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be much related, so I replaced the tag with algebra, precalc.

Comment: @ Deepak. thanks for your suggestions.
@ ajotatxe, it really nothing to do with  combinatorics. Sorry, my apology. But it come from a PDE (partial differential equation after suitable change of variable).

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for solutions in the form $y = f(x)$.

You can easily get an expression for $\alpha = 0$, even though this is just out of your defined range (but you can maybe treat it as a "limiting case" for the lower part of the range). It takes a little more effort to get the solutions for $\alpha = 1$. Solutions for $\alpha = 2$ are possible using the general cubic formula, but this is very tedious, and your answers will be MUCH uglier than the equation you started out with.

And for general non-integral $\alpha$ it is not possible to get a closed form finite solution for $y$ in terms of $x$.

Comment: For $\alpha = 1/2$ you also have a cubic equation to solve.  For $\alpha = 1/3$ or $3$ it's a quartic, also solvable by radicals.

Comment: Good point, I should've written: for general non-integral n.

Comment: @  Deepak: Is there any way I can plot the graph $y$ vs $x$ for $0 < \alpha \leq 2$.

Comment: Your best bet is to use ajotatxe's equation with transposition of $x$ and $y$ for any desired $\alpha$ value and reflect the plot in the line $y=x$ to give the inverse function.

Answer (score 1):

I think that it isn't possible to get an expression $y=f(x)$ for non-integer values of $\alpha$.

The only way, then, is
$$x=\beta^{-1}\ln\left(\frac{(y-1)^{\alpha+1}}{y}\right)$$

Comment: But this reverses the usual relationship between dependent and independent variable, so I don't think this was what was being asked for.

Comment: Neither I do. But writing it doesn't harm.